Diamond Shapes pattern on Bottle side
I am trying to recreate this texture for a bottle in Blender, but I am hitting many problems.
I got a texture that does what I want for the diamond shaped creases on the surface, but when I put it on the model it is messed up.
Any advice?




Have you UV unwrapped your model?

This is definitely a texture coordinates problem. You need to make (or adjust) a map of the 3-D object unwrapped, which will tell the texture in turn how to wrap onto the 3-D object. This is called a UV map, with U and V being the 2-D axes of the map (we don’t want to use X and Y for that because X and Y are already axes in the 3-D space). See this answer for a more complete explanation of materials and textures.
Hope this helps!
